# Array Adapter is not updating in onDataChange() method

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase, android-arrayadapter

This is my ArrayAdapter:

```
public class SackViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PostInfo> {
    private ArrayList<PostInfo> postInfo;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public SackViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,ArrayList<PostInfo> postInfo) {
        super (context, resource);
        this.context = context;
        this.postInfo = postInfo;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e ("Size", String.valueOf (postInfo.size ()));
        return postInfo.size ();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public PostInfo getItem(int i) {
        return postInfo.get (i);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        view  = inflater.inflate (R.layout.card_sack_view, parent,false);
        SelectableRoundedImageView imageView = view.findViewById (R.id.image_view);
        TextView name = view.findViewById (R.id.nameCards);
        TextView username = view.findViewById (R.id.usernameCards);
        imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled (true);
        name.setText (postInfo.get (i).name);
        username.setText (postInfo.get (i).username);
        try{
            Glide.with (context).load (postInfo.get (i).Url).into (imageView);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText (context, e.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
        }
        Log.e ("i", String.valueOf (i));
        return view;
    }
}
```

This is my Main Activity:

```
public class WallActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FloatingActionButton newFloatingButton;
    SackViewAdapter baseAdapter;
    ArrayList<PostInfo> postInfos;
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ().getReference ();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_wall);
        postInfos = new ArrayList<PostInfo> ();
        String isDirectly = getIntent ().getStringExtra ("directly");
        if(isDirectly.equals ("yes")){
            AuthAsyncTask authAsyncTask = new AuthAsyncTask (WallActivity.this);
            authAsyncTask.execute ();
        }
        getData ();
        CardStackView cardStackView = findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        newFloatingButton = findViewById(R.id.newFloatingButton);
        newFloatingButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(WallActivity.this, NewItemActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_up, R.anim.slide_down);
            }
        });
        cardStackView.setCardEventListener(new CardStackView.CardEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCardDragging(float percentX, float percentY) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCardSwiped(SwipeDirection direction) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCardReversed() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCardMovedToOrigin() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCardClicked(int index) {
                Toast.makeText(WallActivity.this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        baseAdapter = new SackViewAdapter (WallActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, postInfos);
        cardStackView.setAdapter(baseAdapter);
    }

    public void getData(){
        reference.addValueEventListener (new ValueEventListener () {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                DataSnapshot posts = dataSnapshot.child ("Posts");
                for (DataSnapshot time: posts.getChildren ()){
                    DataSnapshot url = time.child ("Url");
                    DataSnapshot name = time.child ("Name");
                    DataSnapshot username = time.child ("Username");
                    DataSnapshot date = time.child ("Date");
                    PostInfo postInfo = new PostInfo (String.valueOf (url.getValue ()), String.valueOf (name.getValue ()), String.valueOf (username.getValue ()), String.valueOf (date.getValue ()));
                    postInfos.add (postInfo);
                }
                baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText (WallActivity.this, "Error 411: " + databaseError.getMessage (), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show ();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I get all the data from `getData()` function I update my Array Adapter but after updating real size of the array list comes out to be 7 but the `getView` function takes the value of `i` from 0 to 2 only. It is not adding all the values from the `ArrayList` and it is showing same values again and again rather than showing different values.This is the log when the screen loads as I have added Log.e in `getView`:

```
 04-06 13:04:26.797 10246-10246/lifeline.learn.com.hotornot E/Value of i: 0
04-06 13:04:26.804 10246-10246/lifeline.learn.com.hotornot E/Value of i: 1
04-06 13:04:26.814 10246-10246/lifeline.learn.com.hotornot E/Value of i: 2
```

It is not going over 2. But when I Log in `getCount` it returns 7.

Comment: check your url List size

Comment: post this method also AuthAsyncTask

Comment: better approach will be to create a single arraylist of objects and then pass this arraylist to your adapter

Comment: From your code you are only referencing urls ArrayList. What if there are only 2 value in urls ArrayList? (check getCount() in adapter). So better approach is like what @Navneetヅ suggested.

Comment: All the ArrayList have same size.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your `adapter`'s `getCount()` returns the size of `urls.size ();` but you are passing other 2 arraylists as well, which will only take the size of `urls` arraylist.

If you pass an `Arraylist<UserObject>`, you could add all the data to this object and then return the size as `userObjects.size();`

So the better approach would be to create an object, say `UserObject` and create an arraylist with this object like `Arraylist<UserObject>`

**UserObject.java**

```
public class UserObject {
String urls;
String names;
String usernames;
String dates;

public UserObject(String urls, String names, String usernames, String dates) {
    this.urls = urls;
    this.names = names;
    this.usernames = usernames;
    this.dates = dates;
}
}
```

Declare an arraylist

```
ArrayList<UserObject> userData=new ArrayList<>();
```

Now, change like this

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            DataSnapshot posts = dataSnapshot.child ("Posts");
            for (DataSnapshot time: posts.getChildren ()){
                DataSnapshot url = time.child ("Url");
                DataSnapshot name = time.child ("Name");
                DataSnapshot username = time.child ("Username");
                DataSnapshot date = time.child ("Date");
                UserObject user=new UserObject(String.valueOf (url.getValue ()),String.valueOf (name.getValue ()),String.valueOf (username.getValue ()),String.valueOf (date.getValue ()));
                userData.add(user);
            }
            baseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
        }
```

Your adapter constructor will be like this

```
public SackViewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource,ArrayList<UserObject> userObjects)
```

Comment: It doesn't helped me.

Comment: what *doesn't help* ?  can you specify the issue that you faced with the above method

Comment: Changing ArrayList to UserObject doesn't made any difference.

Comment: were you getting the same size when you used `ArrayList<UserObject>` ?, share the code

Comment: Update the code where you used `ArrayList<UserObject>`

Answer (score 0):

Please do not call these in `getData()`
You have already initialised it onCreate(), and `addValueEventListener` is called everytime there is a change

```
urls.clear ();
        usernames.clear ();
        dates.clear ();
        times.clear ();
```

Also Its better if you use custom object arraylist rather than using three separate lists of type string and manage them

Answer (score 0):

check your url size if their size two then take only 0 to 2.
because you add in adapter in size..

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return urls.size (); // in that provide large size of your data.
}
```

then after when you bind adapter then after used ..

```
notifyDataSetChanged ();
```